# How to notice stdin redirected to directory

Tags: c, stdin, io-redirection

How can you notice in a program that `stdin` is redirected to a directory?

If for example I execute:

```
$ cat < .
```

I get a message from `cat` telling me: `cat: -: Is a directory`. How can I make my C program notice that stdin has been redirected to a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the file descriptor of `stdin` via [`fileno()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3p.html) and then do [`fstat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fstat.3p.html) on the file descriptor.

Here's a simple demonstration:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    struct stat sb;
    if ( fstat(fileno(stdin), &sb) == -1) {
        perror("fstat");
        exit(1);
    }

    switch (sb.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
        case S_IFBLK:  printf("block device\n");            break;
        case S_IFCHR:  printf("character device\n");        break;
        case S_IFDIR:  printf("directory\n");               break;
        case S_IFIFO:  printf("FIFO/pipe\n");               break;
        case S_IFLNK:  printf("symlink\n");                 break;
        case S_IFREG:  printf("regular file\n");            break;
        case S_IFSOCK: printf("socket\n");                  break;
        default:       printf("unknown?\n");                break;
    }
}
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra test.c
$ ./a.out < .
directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the fstat() system call.
See "man fstat" for details.